# Angular 7 to Angular 16 Migration

Tags: angular, eslint, angular-migration

After a lot of struggle, I finally managed to migrate (or part of it) a project in Angular 7 to 16, following the official guide (https://update.angular.io/). There was a problem with the original project, which used a lib called node-sass, which in turn needed node-gyp and a specific version of python installed on the machine, which also needed a c++ complicator, etc. It was tense, I ended up removing this lib from the project and things started to move forward. And I went jumping from version to version. It turns out that I'm at a point now where when I run the project's build, a bunch of errors pop up, that is, they weren't automatically resolved with the lint or with the migrations of the steps.

Does anyone know a way to run a command (I'm not having success with ESlint) that can solve most of the problems that appeared? Silly things like:

> 1 import { RequestOptions, Http, ResponseContentType } from
> '@angular/http'; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Error:
> src/app/shared/shared.module.ts:33:5 - error NG6002: 'TreeTableModule'
> does not appear to be an NgModule class.
>
> Error: src/app/shared/services/fale-conosco-ouvidoria.service.ts:17:9
>
> - error TS2794: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. Did you forget to include 'void' in your type argument to 'Promise'?
>
> 17         resolve();
> ~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts:33:34
> 33     new (executor: (resolve: (value: T | PromiseLike) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> An argument for 'value' was not provided.

I know that some changes won't work, I'll need to do it by hand, but I don't understand why in the updates, angular didn't make some fixes automatically. Some he made. There are also these problems with Ivy:

> This likely means that the library (primeng/treetable) which declares
> TreeTableModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer
> version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider
> checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected
> to be compatible with Ivy.

Sorry for my English.
thanks!